# Python Input loop not taking all inputs

Tags: python-3.x

[python_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fK2X.jpg)

I want to take all inputs and convert them into list of lists. But this program is not taking all inputs as intended. I may have made a basic mistake but I couldn't get my head around it

Comment: Please include the code directly and do not use a screenshot for it.

Comment: You are converting your input to integer and trying to split it, what is the goal there?

Comment: First input is an integer indicating how many lines of further input to be read

Answer (score 0):

Try using readline() rather than input() at every step from start. Because I don't see any problem in the loop, my best guess is because you are using input() you are not reading escape characters which are there in these kind of inputs.